# How to build AOSP for Android Automotive OS?

Tags: android-x86, android-automotive

I have downloaded AOSP codebase for x86 from https://www.android-x86.org/. It builds fine. I wonder how I setup the `config` or `.mk`, so that I can compile or build Android with Android Automotive OS flavor.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer to [/device/generic/car/](https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/car/) repository where AOSP car emulator configuration is available.

The following target variants are available:

```
aosp_car_arm-userdebug
aosp_car_arm64-userdebug
aosp_car_x86-userdebug
aosp_car_x86_64-userdebug
```

I recommend to follow the official documentation for downloading and building AOSP: [Set up for Android Development](https://source.android.com/setup). You can choose car emulator as your build target.

In short:

1. Download some Android repository. In case of Android 10, this could be e.g. using [repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/):

   ```
   $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-10.0.0_r14
   $ repo sync
   ```
2. Setup an environment and choose the car emulator target variant that matches your CPU architecture, e.g.

   ```
   $ . build/envsetup.sh
   $ lunch aosp_car_x86-userdebug
   ```
3. Build the target:

   ```
   $ make
   ```
4. After successful build, run the emulator from command line:

   ```
   $ emulator
   ```

   Note: Usually, for development purposes you would like to run the emulator with some additional options, e.g. `-selinux permissive` (SELinux not enforced) or `-writable-system` (writable system image). Refer to [Start the emulator from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) documentation for more details.

Comment: If I want to deploy Android Automotive on a physical machine, but not just use in an emulator, will this build option give me ISO, system.sfs and other files?