# File "device/generic/goldfish/tools/mk_combined_img.py", line 48 print "'%s' cannot be converted to int" % (line[2])

Tags: python, android, android-source, archlinux, android-automotive

When compiling Android Automotive OS on Arch Linux using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822494/how-to-build-aosp-for-android-automotive-os) you might get an error like this on the last stage of compiling:

```
FAILED: out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system-qemu.img
/bin/bash -c "(export SGDISK=out/host/linux-x86/bin/sgdisk SIMG2IMG=out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img;      device/generic/goldfish/tools/mk_combined_img.py -i out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system-qemu-config.txt -o out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system-qemu.img)"
  File "device/generic/goldfish/tools/mk_combined_img.py", line 48
    print "'%s' cannot be converted to int" % (line[2])
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are getting this error when compiling AOSP on Arch linux, you need to go to the file `/android/device/generic/goldfish/tools/mk_combined_img.py` and change the first line: `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2`

It should compile fine now...

Comment: Arch Linux is rolling release distro, you can get your AOSP build failing after any system update. I personally had that pain many times. This is why I switched to building AOSP in docker containers, for example https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/tools/docker. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173329/1028256

Comment: I personally dislike things like docker containers and snap packages as they have slightly more overhead and a bit more tedious to configure/delete etc